# mysql takes up a lot of memory when writing results to a file

Tags: mysql

I have a query like so:

```
mysql --port=3306 --host=remote_host -e 'select * from pretty_big_table' > data.out
```

The problem is, the table is pretty big and so this takes up a lot of memory. I can't do a `select ... into outfile` because I'm running this on a remote host. Is there any way to dump the data out locally without taking up so much memory?

Comment: Maybe try mysqldump, it has a bunch of options for fine tuning and tweaking how the dump is done, so I'd think you could get the memory requirements down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mysql --quick`.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-command-options.html

> - --quick, -q
>
>   Do not cache each query result, print each row as it is received. This may slow down the server if the output is suspended. With this option, mysql does not use the history file.